# Finding the contraction of a specific differential form given a vector field

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-forms

I am given the following differential form $\eta:=dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ and they ask me to compute the contraction $\omega=\iota_{\nu}\eta$, where $\nu=x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ is the normal exterior unitari  vector field.

My result turns out to be $\omega=x dy\wedge dz-ydx\wedge dz +zdx\wedge dy$ and I just wanted to know if my calculations where correct since I have no way to verify my result.

Comment: If you want your computation to be verified, then you should share your computation, not just the result.

Comment: Could you show your computations so that we can tell if they are right? (the final result is right)

Comment: @Didier . If I am not mistaken we also have $\iota_\nu\,\eta=\star \nu^\flat$ which seems to hold when $\eta$ is the volume form. There is an old [unanswered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912264/is-hodge-star-operation-can-be-understood-as-contraction-after-tensor-product-of) about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Method I:***

Using the short cut [[1]](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ewangzuoq/Courses/16F-Manifolds/Notes/Lec17.pdf)

$$\tag{1}
\iota_\nu\,(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)=dx(\nu)\,(dy\wedge dz)\color{red}-dy(\nu)\,(dx\wedge dz)+dz(\nu)\,(dx\wedge dy)
$$
and
\begin{align}
&dx(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})=dy(\frac{\partial}{\partial y})=dz(\frac{\partial}{\partial y})=1\,,\\
&dx(\frac{\partial}{\partial y})=dx(\frac{\partial}{\partial z})=0\,,
dy(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})=dy(\frac{\partial}{\partial z})=0\,,
dz(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})=dz(\frac{\partial}{\partial y})=0\,,\tag{2}
\end{align}
gives you directly
$$\tag{3}
\iota_\nu\,(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)=x\,dy\wedge dz\color{red}-y\,dx\wedge dz +z\,dx\wedge dy\,.
$$
***Method II:***

Assuming that $\eta=dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ is the volume form of $\mathbb R^3$ we have the [Hodge star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Three_dimensions) as
$$\tag{4}
\star\,dx=dy\wedge dz,\quad\star\,dy=dz\wedge dx,\quad\star\,dz=dx\wedge dy\,.
$$
This allows to write (1) as
\begin{align}
\iota_\nu\,(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)&=dx(\nu)\,(\star\,dx)\color{red}{+}dy(\nu)\,(\star\,dy)+dz(\nu)\,(\star\,dz)\\[2mm]
&=\star\,(dx(\nu)\,dx+dy(\nu)\,dy+dz(\nu)\,dz)\,.\tag{5}
\end{align}
"Lowering indices" of an arbitrary vector field $\nu=\nu^x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\nu^y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\nu^z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ by the musical isomorphism gives
the one-form
$$\tag{6}
\nu_\flat=\nu_x\,dx+\nu_y\,dy+\nu_z\,dz\,.
$$
Observing that, in $\mathbb R^3\,,$ we have $\nu_x=\nu^x,\nu_y=\nu^y,\nu_z=\nu^z\,,$ and further that
$$
dx(\nu)=\nu^x\,,\quad dy(\nu)=\nu^y\,,\quad dz(\nu)=\nu^z
$$
holds we can write (5) very neatly as
$$\tag{7}\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Big|}
\iota_\nu(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)=\star\,\nu_\flat\,.\quad}
$$
Using this with $\nu=x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ gives you $\nu_\flat=x\,dx+y\,dy+z\,dz$ which directly leads to (3).

***Method III:***

By definition:
\begin{align}\tag{8}
\omega:=\iota_\nu\,\eta(\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}):=\eta(\nu,\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v})
\end{align}
where $\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v}$ are arbitrary vector fields. To check that $\omega$ is of the form
$$\tag{9}
\omega=x\,dy\wedge dz-y\,dx\wedge dz +z\,dx\wedge dy
$$
it might be a good exercise to

- write out all wedge products
  \begin{align}
  dx\wedge dy&=dx\otimes dy-dy\otimes dx\,,\\
  &\vdots\\
  dx\wedge dy\wedge dz&=dx\otimes dy\otimes dz-dx\otimes dz\otimes dy\\
  &~-dy\otimes dx\otimes dz+dy\otimes dz\otimes dx\\
  &~+dz\otimes dx\otimes dy-dz\otimes dy\otimes dx\,;
  \end{align}
- plug $\nu=x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ into the first slot of
  $$\tag{10}
  \eta=dx\wedge dy\wedge dz\,,
  $$
  that is
  \begin{align}
  \eta(\nu,\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v})&=x\,(dy\otimes dz)(\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v})-x\,(dz\otimes dy)(\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v})\\
  &-y\,(dx\otimes dz)(\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v})+y\,(dz\otimes dx)(\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v})\\
  &+
  z\,(dx\otimes dy)(\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v})
  -
  z\,(dy\otimes dx)(\boldsymbol{u},\boldsymbol{v})\,;
  \end{align}
  and
- plug the basis vector fields $\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ in for $\boldsymbol{u}$ and $\boldsymbol{v}\,.$

This gives
\begin{align}
\omega(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y})&=z\,,
&\eta(\nu,\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y})&=z\,,\\
\omega(\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial x})&=-z\,,
&\eta(\nu,\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial x})&=-z\,,\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
It is not hard to see that $\omega$ and $\eta(\nu,.,.)$ agree on all
combinations. This proves again the equation (9).

The volume form $\eta$ and its contraction $\omega$ along $\nu$  have the interesting property that
$$
d\omega=d(\iota_\nu\,\eta)=3\eta={\rm div}\nu\;\eta
$$
which is easily seen from (9). The Stokes theorem $\int_{\partial V}\omega=\int_Vd\omega$ is here Gauss' divergence theorem and
in this particular case it takes the form
$$
\int_{\partial V}\iota_\nu\,\eta=\int_V{\rm div}\nu\;\eta\,.
$$